# Menu is missing under Resources - XAMARIN

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a menu on my app bar but why I can't find it under Resource? As you can see, it has color red under it's name. I tried to right click on it but it only says generate menu method. I can't rebuild and deploy it since it gives me that kind of weird error. Also what happen after that is my VS can't read even the Resource itself. I can only solve it if I add another activity or delete it or to restart the VS.

[image]

Here is my Menu folder.

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7Oo.png)

Here is my full code for activity

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Entities;

namespace RBankCI
{
    [Activity(Label = "PDRN", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.FullScreenBaseDesign")]
    public class Activity_PDRN : AppCompatActivity, IActivityInterface
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Layout_PDRNForm);
            Title = string.Empty;
            i1_setupActionBar();
        }

        public void i1_setupActionBar()
        {
            // Initialize Support ToolBar
            SupportToolbar toolBar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);
            toolBar.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.AppBarBackgrounWithTitle);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        public void i2_initialization()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void i3_deserializeIntentExtras()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void i4_setUpAllClickable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void i5_setTextChangeBehaviour()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void i6_setTextFieldValues()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region Override OnCreateOptionsMenu()
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a menu setting
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="menu">Menu</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            //Here is the problem. My VS can't read the Menu after Resource

            // Create Menu Action
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_form, menu);

            return true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override OnOptionsItemSelected()
        /// <summary>
        /// Event when a user clicks one of the ActionBar Icons
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">Action Item</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            // Open Navigation Drawer
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                // User click menu icon
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    OnBackPressed();
                    return true;
                case Android.Resource.Id.menu_clear: //here, I can see and error a constant value is expected. This id is under the menu_form.xml
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Clear All Fields", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.menu_attach: //here, I can see and error a constant value is expected. This id is under the menu_form.xml
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Attach Photo", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override OnBackPressed()
        /// <summary>
        /// Override OnBackPressed
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            try
            {
                Finish();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ENT_NegativeResponse.somethingWentWrong, 0).Show();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my menu_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--For all properties see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <!-- Declaring Menu Actions -->
  <item
  android:id="@+id/menu_clear"
  android:title="Clear All Fields"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear_fields_png_x3"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

  <item
  android:id="@+id/menu_attach"
  android:title="Attach Photo"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_image_png_x3"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: post your menu_form.xml

Comment: and What Is Resource.Menu.. Please Don't Copy Screen Shot. Instead Post Your code

Comment: I take screenshots since we can't see the red line under Menu if I just copy the code .

Comment: Can someone explain about the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Use this-:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);
```

In this case Import R file that is of your current package

Comment: still nothing. I think it just instantiate the MenuInflater to variable inflater .

Comment: Try changing Resource to R file and try importing that as popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.medication_list_more_option);

Comment: No I can't. R is for android and Resource is for xamarin . Camel Casing and Some codes are slightly different like what you mentioned getMenuInflater is MenuInflater in xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

> Menu is missing under Resources - XAMARIN

Check if the resource id has been generated in `Resource.designer.cs`.

[image]

In my project, the resource id is :

```
public partial class Id
{
    ...
    // aapt resource value: 0x7f0b007b
    public const int menu_attach = 2131427451;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f0b007a
    public const int menu_clear = 2131427450;
    ...
}

...

public partial class Menu
{

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f0d0000
    public const int menu_form = 2131558400;

    static Menu()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }

    private Menu()
    {
    }
}
```

## Solution :

**If it has not been generated, usually clean and rebuilding the project will generate it again, unless there is a syntax error somewhere.**

Comment: Nah it's not generating Menu, menu_form or even the menu_clear and menu_attach. If I comment the MenuInflater, my program works. But not if I try to initialize it.

Comment: @jace, delete your project bin and obj files and rebuild again, then you should `Menu` resource in your project.

Comment: I did that once, even the file under xamarin folder on appdata. restarted and done anything I could but I don't know why.

Comment: I already found the solution. Thanks to your comment. I'll just post is as an answer if ever others will have same situation as mine

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Updating Xamarin for Visual Studio solved the issue for missing Menu under Resource . Got the blue-green color after

---

I found it back from my Resource.Designer.cs although it still have a message under it: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Menu' and for the buttons they have "A constant value is required". But still it is working with redlines.

For reference of others, this is what I did.

My VS.Xamarin is good with my menu before until it prompts me with message that it is not recognizable. Here are my steps that I tried:
1. Restarted the VS
2. Removed bin and obj under project
3. Removed xamarin folder content under user/appdata/local/xamarin
4. Clean and Rebuild as many as I can
5. Create new menu folder under resource
6. Create menu file from add button but I think this is also a problem

**Part of Soution**
menu under add button generates menu_form.xml file while xamarin read an .axml format. So my solution is to create a layout, copy what my menu_form.xml have and clean then rebuild. Menu, menu_form and it's elements showed up to Resource.Designer.cs after that.

It's actually a problem for me since it is working before but suddenly stopped and gave me an error.
Still I have an error regarding Resource.Menu the same from the beginning with a red line yet it's working well. I don't know why my VS gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've edit it:

[image]

(Change BuildAction to AndroidResource)